# How to change default sorting icon on table header column on React Material-Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Can I change the default sorting icon on React Material-Table table header column ? ex. I want to change asc sorting icon to ArrowDownward and desc sorting icon to ArrowUpward. I try to set SortArrow icons props on MaterialTable but its show on every table header columns even its not active sorting column. Please help.

[Material-Table](https://material-table.com/#/)

Code:

```
<MaterialTable ... icons={{ SortArrow: () => <ArrowDownwardIcon /> }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to forward the refs like this:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';  
...
<MaterialTable>  
     icons={{ SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownwardIcon{...props} ref={ref}/>)}}
<MaterialTable>
```

This will pass the required props to your custom icon and it will work.

Comment: I try this already but not working. The asc sorting icon still be ArrowUpwardIcon (I want to change to ArrowDownwardIcon). Thank for your help.

Comment: Maybe it just works differently than you expect. Did you try using the ArrowUpwardIcon?

Comment: The problem is solved after try using the ArrowUpwardIcon. Thank you very much.

Comment: `<MaterialTable
          data={data}
          icons={{
            Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Checkbox
              {...props} ref={ref}
              icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankOutlinedIcon className="test" />}
              checkedIcon={<CheckBoxOutlinedIcon />}
              />)}}
          tableRef={ref}
        /> `  not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass your component as a value

```
     icons={{
              SortArrow: ArrowDropUpIcon,
           }}
```